# Import CSV using pandas with header size different from content size

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file with content line length different than the header line length using pandas.

*example.csv*

```
COL1;COL2
1;A;A
2;B;B
3;C;C
```

Expected result:

| COL1 | COL2 | Unnamed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A |
| 2 | B | B |
| 3 | C | C |

The results I'm getting:

**Input:**

```
pd.read_csv(
    "example.csv",
    sep=";")
```

**Output:**

| (Index) | COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A |
| 2 | B | B |
| 3 | C | C |

Using `index_col = False`:

**Input:**

```
pd.read_csv(
    "example.csv",
    sep=";",
    index_col = False)
```

**Output:**

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

Is there a way to import *example.csv* using pandas and get the expected results?

**EDIT:** `Unnamed` is the default column name pandas give, in some situations, to an unknown column. No need to be named as `Unnamed`.

Comment: you can pass columns names to `read_csv` using `names = [' ', ' ' , ' ']`

Comment: @MD That's an option, but not what I'm looking for. Usually the files I work on have column and row sizes unknown.

Answer (score 1):

I would just read as normal, reset the index and shift the columns:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=';').reset_index()
df.columns = df.columns[1:].tolist()+['Unnamed']
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I would need to generate the `Unnamed` names. If possible would be better if pandas did it (as it does for other cases).